# Sails js render partial view

Tags: node.js, sails.js, partial-views

I'm new in SailsJS so i have a question about rendering partial views.

I've came from .NET world and partial views in ASP.NET MVC are much more clever than in sails. In .NET MVC i can provide some controller as partial view path and this controller will be executed and partial view will be rendered with that controller data.

For example I want to show some account info in the corner of my website. So in .NET i can call partial view, providing controller path, this controller will query account info, provide it to partial view, and then this result will be inserted to main view.
In Sails i can call partial view, but all data (locals) for partial view will be pushed there from main view. So i have to put account information in every controller in application?

How can i solve this problem? 
In other questions i've found that I can take username from `req.session` but it does not solve all cases. How can i show three random topics in page footer for example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the wrong place about the partial views.
This is a front-end problem .What I use for such partial views is Angular UI-router . Actually I am not sure if using angular is in the scope of the solution for you,So I'll keep this short . If you feel my method is useful ,you can comment it ,and I'll elaborate further on how to do it .

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the template engine, that you use.

With ejs you can use `<%- include('someview') %>` or `<%- include('someview', { mydata: { foo: bar} }) %>`
The latter allows the include file to be called several times with diff data. E.g. `<%- include('someview', { mydata: foo }) %>` will copy foo (from locals) to the mydata key. This will be added to locals, so all other locals are available too.

As for providing the actual data, you can use a sails service. Just add data to res.locals.myKeyForTheInclude.

You will have to call the service each time.
But you can add it in config/http as a middleware.

```
middleware: {
  myFoo: myService.myFunc,
  order: [
   ...
  'myFoo', // before router
  'router',
   ...
],
```

All that is left is that each template needs the include.
You can not avoid that, only the template knows where the include should be.
But if you use a layout, that maybe it fits into the layout.